# How to edit and delete data in DataGridView?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm developing a desktop application in VB.NET in which I want to do editing and deleting and adding of new rows in a DataGridView. How can I achieve that?

getting error "Conversion from string "Update  dbo.Trans set BCode='1'," to type 'Double' is not valid."

The code which I tried:

con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=USER\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Sap;Integrated Security=True")

```
    If (TbCode.Text = "" Or TbItem.Text = "" Or TbWgt.Text = "") Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the columns")
    Else
        con.Open()

        cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Update  dbo.Trans set BCode='" + TbCode.Text + "',BName='" + Label2.Text + "',ICode='" + TbItem.Text + "',IName='" + Label3.Text + "',Qty='" + TbQty.Text + "',Weight='" + TbWgt.Text + "',RWeight='" + Label4.Text + "',Rate='" + Rate + "'  where date=@date and depot=@depot and BCode=@bcode and Icode=@icode", con)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depot", TbDepot.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", TbItem.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", IDate.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcode", TbCode.Text)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()


    End If


    con.Close()

    Call Fillgrid()
    Call emptyfun()

End Sub
```

Comment: is id1 supposed to be what you are wanting in the SQL statement? Because you have id. And why are you not using a parameter for that like you do with Date and Depot? Are you receiving any error messages? There's a lot of missing code to properly set up and execute that SqlCommand.

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575015/programmatically-change-selection-on-datagridview-net)

Comment: sir i tried this code to update the grid value by retriving the value in text box.

Comment: Does your Trans table have a primary Key?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are using the plus sign to concatenate strings and should be using the ampersand.

This will be cause by the compiler if you turn Strict Option On.

This is your updated code.

```
cmd1 = New SqlCommand("Update  dbo.Trans set BCode='" & TbCode.Text & "',BName='" & Label2.Text & "',ICode='" & TbItem.Text & "',IName='" & Label3.Text & "',Qty='" & TbQty.Text & "',Weight='" & TbWgt.Text & "',RWeight='" & Label4.Text & "',Rate='" & Rate & "'  where date=@date and depot=@depot and BCode=@bcode and Icode=@icode", con)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@depot", TbDepot.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@icode", TbItem.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", IDate.Text)
        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bcode", TbCode.Text)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

However, you should technically be using parameters for the entire update statement, not just the where clause.  Another recommendation is to explicitly define the data type of the parameter, rather than using AddWithValue.